# Calculate proportion of values within subgroup

Tags: r, dataframe, data-wrangling

I am attempting to calculate the proportion of `values` within `type` by `cond`, but am having trouble calculating the sum of type by cond first. Does anyone have advice? Thank you!

toy dataset

```
cond  type  value
x      A     2
x      A     4
x      B     1
y      C     7
y      D     2
y      D     3
y      E     5
...    ...   ...
```

Desired output:

So for example, the proportion of `A` would be 6/(6+1) = .857

```
cond type sum  proportion
x     A    6   .857
x     B    1   .143
y     C    7   .411
y     D    5   .294
y     E    5   .294
...   ...   ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a group by `sum` in `summarise`.  By default, the last grouping is dropped after the `summarise`, so, use `mutate` to divide the 'Sum' by the `sum` of 'Sum' column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(cond, type) %>%
    summarise(Sum = sum(value)) %>%
    mutate(proportion = Sum/sum(Sum))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
# Groups:   cond [2]
#  cond  type    Sum proportion
#  <chr> <chr> <int>      <dbl>
#1 x     A         6      0.857
#2 x     B         1      0.143
#3 y     C         7      0.412
#4 y     D         5      0.294
#5 y     E         5      0.294
```

---

Or using `prop.table` from `base R`

```
prop.table(xtabs(value ~ cond + type, df1), 1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(cond = c("x", "x", "x", "y", "y", "y", "y"), type = c("A", 
"A", "B", "C", "D", "D", "E"), value = c(2L, 4L, 1L, 7L, 2L, 
3L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option will be:

```
transform(aggregate(value~.,df,sum), prop = ave(value, cond,FUN = prop.table))

  cond type value      prop
1    x    A     6 0.8571429
2    x    B     1 0.1428571
3    y    C     7 0.4117647
4    y    D     5 0.2941176
5    y    E     5 0.2941176
```

Answer (score -1):

For completeness, here is a `data.table` solution :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, sum(value), .(cond, type)][, proportion := V1/sum(V1), cond][]
#OR using prop.table
#setDT(df)[, sum(value), .(cond, type)][, proportion := prop.table(V1), cond][]

#   cond type V1 proportion
#1:    x    A  6  0.8571429
#2:    x    B  1  0.1428571
#3:    y    C  7  0.4117647
#4:    y    D  5  0.2941176
#5:    y    E  5  0.2941176
```